# VBScript to append a table to the existing Word Document and add borders to the table

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, append

Requirement: Open an existing Word document and append a table at the end of the document. Also add borders to the table.

Tried the following code:this doesn't give me the expected results.

```
dim doc1 
Set objWord = CreateObject("word.application") 
objWord.Documents.Open "C:\test.docx"
 const END_OF_STORY=6
 objWord.Selection.EndKey 6
 Set objRange = objWord.Selection.Range                
 Const wdCollapseEnd = 0
objRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd    

objWord.Visible = false 
set doc1 = objWord.ActiveDocument 

doc1.Tables.Add objRange, 4, 4
set tab1 =doc1.Tables(1)
tab1.Cell(1,1).Range.Text = "Test" 
tab1.Cell(1,2).Range.Text = "Test1"
tab1.Cell(1,3).Range.Text = "Test2"
tab1.Cell(1,4).Range.Text = "Test3"
doc1.Tables.Add objRange, 1, 1 
set tab2 = doc1.Tables(1) 
tab2.Cell(1,1).Range.Text = "test7" 

objWord.ActiveDocument.Save
    objWord.Quit
    Set objWord = Nothing
```

Comment: HOW does it not give the expected result?

Comment: It does not add the table to the end of the document and could you also  let me know how i could add a border to this table

Comment: First thing you need to do is assign the document to the doc1 variable when the document is opened: Set doc1 = objWord.Documents.Open... Then don't use Selection, instead: Set objRange = doc1.Content. Then Set tab1 = doc1.Tables.Add and see if that helps. For the borders: first try recording creating borders in a macro to get the basic syntax. Since I have no idea what kind of border(s) and where it makes no sense for me to try and provide any code...

Comment: Dear All. I had the same issue. Was there any resolution for this Leena.